# Updating Item from Pivot Table Fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have item_color and item_size pivot tables, and would like to update my size and color fields using their field values, and an not exactly sure where to start. Here's what I have so far.

ItemSize.php

```
<?php

class ItemSize extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'item_size';
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function item() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Item');
    }
}
```

ItemColor.php

```
<?php

class ItemColor extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'item_color';
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function item() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Item');
    }
}
```

VendorController

```
public function postVendorUpdateItems ($id)
         {

             $input     = Input::all();

             $items = Item::find($id);
             $validator = Validator::make($input, 
               [ 'item_name'     => 'max:50',
                 'item_id'       => 'max:50',
                 'normalprice'   => 'numeric',
                 'karmaprice'    => 'numeric',
                 'asin'          => 'max:50',
               ]);

             if($validator->passes())
             {

                 $items->name           = $input['item_name'];
                 $items->normalprice    = $input['normalprice'];
                 $items->karmaprice     = $input['karmaprice'];
                 $items->asin           = $input['asin'];
                 $items->id             = $input['item_id'];
                 $items->save();
                 return Redirect::route('account-vendor-index')
                                ->with('global', 'You have updated your item.');
             }

             return Redirect::route('account-vendor-index')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->with('global', 'Your item could not be updated.');
         }
```

View

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{{url('account/vendor/update/items')}}/{{$item->id}}">
                <input type="hidden" id="brand_id" placeholder="brand_id" value="{{$brand->id}}" name="brand_id">
                <input type="hidden" id="item_id" placeholder="item_id" value="{{$item->id}}" name="item_id">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="colors" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Colors</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="colors" name="colors" placeholder="@foreach($item->colors as $color){{$color->color}}@endforeach" value="">
                  </div>
                  <button type="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add color</button>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-offset-3 showColors">
                    @foreach($item->colors as $color)
                      {{$color->color}}
                    @endforeach
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Sizes</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <select id="selectSizes" multiple="multiple" class="form-control selectSizes" name="sizes">
                            <option value="XS (0-2)">XS (0-2)</option>
                            <option value="S (4-6)">S (4-6)</option>
                            <option value="M (8-10)">M (8-10)</option>
                            <option value="L (12-14)">L (12-14)</option>
                            <option value="XL (16-18)">XL (16-18)</option>
                            <option value="XXL (20-22)">XXL (20-22)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group bot-0">
                  <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-main btn-sm">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean with this "my size and color fields using their field values"? What exactly are the `my fields` and `their fields`? Please be clear.

Comment: The 'color' field in the item_color pivot table. https://i.imgur.com/7b55s7u.png and the size field in the item_size table https://i.imgur.com/j3nUci0.png

Answer (score 0):

item_size and item_color are not pivot tables. They are in fact a one to one relationship with your schema. If want you truly want are pivot tables, you need to define a color and a size table, then create a many-to-many relationship. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Then to update related models, you'll use the attach, sync, detach, etc. methods.

Also, what version of Laravel are you running? If you're running 5.1+ look into form request validation. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation

That will remove all the validation logic from your controller.

Comment: A 'true' pivot may not be what I need. I just want to store many colors for many items and many sizes for many items whatever way i can.

Comment: I'm running Laravel 4

Comment: Sounds like pivot tables are exactly what you need in this case. You are describing a classic many-to-many relationship. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many